# Geometric intuition behind feasible direction

Tags: geometry, linear-programming, intuition

I'm currently watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ANFEer88VQ&list=PL10NOnsbP5Q4rgf9evv4wUe9wcgW61_6c&index=5) about feasible directions hoping to eventually understand why feasible basic solutions = vertices of the polyhedron, and I don't quite understand this slide:
[image]

I get why $Ad$ must be equal to $0$ (otherwise we don't have $Ax=b$ anymore which is explained in the previous slide, shown at the end of this post). But I don't understand geometrically why this would lead to the direction being feasible. If we are on an interior point, why do we need $Ad = 0$? Aren't all directions available to us?

As for the second bullet point, I do understand the interpretation (little drawing on the right of the slide helps), so it's really the $Ad$ must be equal to $0$ condition that is bothering me.

Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> "If we are on an interior point, why do we need $Ad = 0$? Aren't all
> directions available to us?"

The polyhedron $P = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid Ax = b, x \geq 0\}$ has empty interior (unless $A = 0$). The condition Ax = b restricts us to an affine subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ (such as a plane in $\mathbb R^3$), and the condition that $x \geq 0$ restricts us further.

Comment: Hi, I’m not sure to understand what you mean by empty interior? Ax=b could restrict us to a cube right? (In $\mathbb{R}^3$)

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Suppose $A$ is a real $1 \times 3$ matrix, for example, and $b \in \mathbb R^3$. Then the equation $Ax = b$ typically restricts us to a plane in $\mathbb R^3$. Alternatively, suppose that $A$ is a $2 \times 3$ matrix. Then the equation $Ax = b$ typically restricts us to a line in $\mathbb R^3$ (the intersection of two planes). The equation $Ax = b$ by itself could not restrict us to a cube in $\mathbb R^3$. (It might be useful to spend some time reading about subspaces in linear algebra.)

Comment: But in 2 dimensions, if I force x + y <= 4 and x >=0 and y >= 0 I still have a surface and not a line? And when i introduce slack variables i end up with a system Ax = b.

Comment: Or is it that after i introduce slack variables the geometric representation changes and we get up in dimensions? Maybe that's where I got confused ...